# codeigniter form validation on array not form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper, codeigniter

i want validate my form input field or you want to say i have an array and i want to validate that array using codeigniter

Example :
i have array like :

```
$array['obj_type']='sample';
$array['obj_id']='44';
$array['user_id']='34566';
```

and my form validation config as like :

```
'validatedata' =>  array(
      array(
            'field' => 'obj_type',
            'label' => 'No Type Define here',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),  
        array(
            'field' => 'obj_id',
            'label' => 'No any item selected here',
            'rules' => 'required|is_natural_no_zero'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'No user logged in',
            'rules' => 'required|is_natural_no_zero'
        ),
    ),
```

and when i use form validate its not validate array

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('validatedata')) {
} else {
echo validation_errors();
}
```

its print all error which define on on validatedata config array;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just use

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($array);
```

then i validate form

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('validatedata')) {
echo "sucess";
} else {
echo validation_errors();
}
```

now its works fine and good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load form validation library in your controller..

```
$this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
```

Comment: The No Type Define here field is required.
The No any item selected here field is required
The No user logged in field is required

Comment: if you submit the form with all fields empty then it will show validation error

Comment: at this time i have no any form i just have an array and i want to check this array is validate or not.

Comment: form validation will works only form submit....you wrote the rules for the array which will get after the form submit

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the data to the form_validation library:

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($array);
```

and then you can use

```
$this->form_validation->run('validatedata')
```

as intended.

If you want to validate multiple arrays, you'll have to call `reset_validation()` after validating each array.

Check system/libraries/Form_validation.php (around line 255, depending on your version of CI) for more information.